# Why some classes in tailwind is not present in laravel install?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I wonder why tailwind admin templates won't work, then later I figured out that some classes are not present in my app.css.

I have followed the installation in https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel.

These are the classes in my app.css.

Why some classes are not present in app.css?
ex: bg-gray-800, w-full, h-20 etc..

```css
/*
! tailwindcss v3.0.22 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com
*//*
1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4)
2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width. (https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116)
*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  border-width: 0; /* 2 */
  border-style: solid; /* 2 */
  border-color: #e5e7eb; /* 2 */
}

::before,
::after {
  --tw-content: '';
}

/*
1. Use a consistent sensible line-height in all browsers.
2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
3. Use a more readable tab size.
4. Use the user's configured `sans` font-family by default.
*/

html {
  line-height: 1.5; /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
  -moz-tab-size: 4; /* 3 */
  -o-tab-size: 4;
     tab-size: 4; /* 3 */
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"; /* 4 */
}

/*
1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
2. Inherit line-height from `html` so users can set them as a class directly on the `html` element.
*/

body {
  margin: 0; /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit; /* 2 */
}

/*
1. Add the correct height in Firefox.
2. Correct the inheritance of border color in Firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190655)
3. Ensure horizontal rules are visible by default.
*/

hr {
  height: 0; /* 1 */
  color: inherit; /* 2 */
  border-top-width: 1px; /* 3 */
}

/*
Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
*/

abbr:where([title]) {
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
          text-decoration: underline dotted;
}

/*
Remove the default font size and weight for headings.
*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}

/*
Reset links to optimize for opt-in styling instead of opt-out.
*/

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

/*
Add the correct font weight in Edge and Safari.
*/

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/*
1. Use the user's configured `mono` font family by default.
2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
*/

code,
kbd,
samp,
pre {
  font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct font size in all browsers.
*/

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/*
Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in all browsers.
*/

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/*
1. Remove text indentation from table contents in Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=999088, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201297)
2. Correct table border color inheritance in all Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935729, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195016)
3. Remove gaps between table borders by default.
*/

table {
  text-indent: 0; /* 1 */
  border-color: inherit; /* 2 */
  border-collapse: collapse; /* 3 */
}

/*
1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
3. Remove default padding in all browsers.
*/

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit; /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit; /* 1 */
  color: inherit; /* 1 */
  margin: 0; /* 2 */
  padding: 0; /* 3 */
}

/*
Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge and Firefox.
*/

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Remove default button styles.
*/

button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
  background-color: transparent; /* 2 */
  background-image: none; /* 2 */
}

/*
Use the modern Firefox focus style for all focusable elements.
*/

:-moz-focusring {
  outline: auto;
}

/*
Remove the additional `:invalid` styles in Firefox. (https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/2f9eacd9d3d995c937b4251a5557d95d494c9be1/layout/style/res/forms.css#L728-L737)
*/

:-moz-ui-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

/*
Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome and Firefox.
*/

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/*
Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/*
1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
*/

[type='search'] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px; /* 2 */
}

/*
Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
*/

::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
  font: inherit; /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct display in Chrome and Safari.
*/

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/*
Removes the default spacing and border for appropriate elements.
*/

blockquote,
dl,
dd,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
hr,
figure,
p,
pre {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

legend {
  padding: 0;
}

ol,
ul,
menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*
Prevent resizing textareas horizontally by default.
*/

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

/*
1. Reset the default placeholder opacity in Firefox. (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3300)
2. Set the default placeholder color to the user's configured gray 400 color.
*/

input::-moz-placeholder, textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1; /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af; /* 2 */
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder, textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1; /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af; /* 2 */
}

input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
  opacity: 1; /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af; /* 2 */
}

/*
Set the default cursor for buttons.
*/

button,
[role="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*
Make sure disabled buttons don't get the pointer cursor.
*/
:disabled {
  cursor: default;
}

/*
1. Make replaced elements `display: block` by default. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
2. Add `vertical-align: middle` to align replaced elements more sensibly by default. (https://github.com/jensimmons/cssremedy/issues/14#issuecomment-634934210)
   This can trigger a poorly considered lint error in some tools but is included by design.
*/

img,
svg,
video,
canvas,
audio,
iframe,
embed,
object {
  display: block; /* 1 */
  vertical-align: middle; /* 2 */
}

/*
Constrain images and videos to the parent width and preserve their intrinsic aspect ratio. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
*/

img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/*
Ensure the default browser behavior of the `hidden` attribute.
*/

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

*, ::before, ::after {
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
.top-0 {
  top: 0px;
}
.right-0 {
  right: 0px;
}
.mx-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.ml-1 {
  margin-left: 0.25rem;
}
.mt-2 {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
.mr-2 {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
.ml-2 {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
.mt-4 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.ml-4 {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
.mt-8 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.ml-12 {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}
.-mt-px {
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.h-5 {
  height: 1.25rem;
}
.h-8 {
  height: 2rem;
}
.h-16 {
  height: 4rem;
}
.min-h-screen {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.w-5 {
  width: 1.25rem;
}
.w-8 {
  width: 2rem;
}
.w-auto {
  width: auto;
}
.max-w-6xl {
  max-width: 72rem;
}
.grid-cols-1 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
.items-center {
  align-items: center;
}
.justify-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.border-t {
  border-top-width: 1px;
}
.border-gray-200 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(229 231 235 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}
.bg-white {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
.bg-gray-100 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(243 244 246 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
.p-6 {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}
.py-4 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.px-6 {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}
.pt-8 {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.text-sm {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}
.text-lg {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
}
.font-semibold {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.leading-7 {
  line-height: 1.75rem;
}
.text-gray-200 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(229 231 235 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.text-gray-300 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(209 213 219 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.text-gray-400 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(156 163 175 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.text-gray-500 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(107 114 128 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.text-gray-600 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(75 85 99 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.text-gray-700 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(55 65 81 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.text-gray-900 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(17 24 39 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.underline {
  -webkit-text-decoration-line: underline;
          text-decoration-line: underline;
}
.antialiased {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.shadow {
  --tw-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1), 0 1px 2px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 1px 3px 0 var(--tw-shadow-color), 0 1px 2px -1px var(--tw-shadow-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow);
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

  .dark\:border-gray-700 {
    --tw-border-opacity: 1;
    border-color: rgb(55 65 81 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
  }

  .dark\:bg-gray-900 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(17 24 39 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  }

  .dark\:bg-gray-800 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(31 41 55 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  }

  .dark\:text-gray-500 {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(107 114 128 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
  }

  .dark\:text-white {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
  }

  .dark\:text-gray-400 {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(156 163 175 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
  }
}
@media (min-width: 640px) {

  .sm\:ml-0 {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }

  .sm\:block {
    display: block;
  }

  .sm\:h-20 {
    height: 5rem;
  }

  .sm\:items-center {
    align-items: center;
  }

  .sm\:justify-start {
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  .sm\:justify-between {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .sm\:rounded-lg {
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
  }

  .sm\:px-6 {
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
  }

  .sm\:pt-0 {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }

  .sm\:text-left {
    text-align: left;
  }

  .sm\:text-right {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .md\:grid-cols-2 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  }

  .md\:border-t-0 {
    border-top-width: 0px;
  }

  .md\:border-l {
    border-left-width: 1px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {

  .lg\:px-8 {
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you running npm watch? First you need to tell tailwind which files to track and than `npm run watch`.
Tailwind then reads all classes in the tracked blades and builds only those.

in guide its point 4 and 6
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel

Than you can add this `mix.disableNotifications();` into webpack.mix.js to disable notification.

Comment: thank you, solved just my problem! by the way where did you found this answer?

Comment: @Pusoy I found the answer in your link to tailwind/laravel doc. ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can add the paths to the admin files in the setup here

```
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
  ],
```

i presume it will be

```
    "./resources/admin/**/*.blade.php",
```

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and I made 100% sure of doing what the instructions on the Tailwind website says. When you run 'npm run dev' the app.css file is supposed to be populated with Tailwind rules yet not all are there, which makes no sense. How does it decide what not to load and what to load.

Comment: @calvincani add this to your webpack.mix.js mix.disableNotifications(); thanks to jakub